Use object key values as keys on new object
Trying to get better with data mutating in vanilla JS and have not been successful here.
I am just trying to use the values of one object to create keys for another format.
Also tried things like string interpolation ${} etc, can someone please show my error? The example in comment is what I'm after so like
var = { x: 'left', y: 'top', z: 'front' } => becomes => {left: top, extra: { front: true }
but obviously struggling with syntax, thank you!
const obj1 = {
  aKey: 'a_value',
  bKey: 'b_value',
  cKey: 'c_value'
}

/************************* pseudo what I want to turn this into:
  obj2 = {
    [a_value]: [b_value],
    adhocKey: {
      [c_value]: true
    }
  }
*/

const obj2 = {
  obj1[aKey]: obj1[bKey],
  adhocKey: {
    obj1[cKey]: true
  }
}
console.log(obj1)

const obj3 = {
  obj1.aKey: obj1.bKey,
  adhocKey: {
    obj1.cKey]: true
  }
}
console.log(obj2)

See description details

[obj1['aKey']]: obj1['bKey']

I'm seeing SyntaxError: missing : after property id" in reference to obj1[aKey]: obj1[bKey], You can't dynamically set keys like this while creating Object obj2, but after you create obj2, you can do obj2[obj1[aKey]] = obj1[bKey].

Why should the output be {left: 'top'} and not {front: 'left'} or {top: 'front'}?

You can use the value of x (or z) as a key by using the bracket-notation e.g. [x]: ...
To get the value of y, you should use the dot-notation.


const
  original = { x: 'left', y: 'top', z: 'front' },
  result = { [original.x]: original.y, extra: { [original.z]: true } };

console.log(result); // { left: top, extra: { front: true }



